# Why does this limit work?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, infinity, functions

Let $h(x)= (1+1/x)^x$ and $g(x)$ be another function.

Now suppose $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x)= \infty$. Then $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} h(g(x))$ =$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} h(x)=e$.

I would like to see a **rigorous** proof(or a reference for the proof) why this is true ? Exactly, what properties of limit are being used to get this result?

Comment: Do you have to question typed right? Because as it is, $h(x) \to \infty$.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} h(x) = C \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ if and only if, for any sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $x_n \rightarrow \infty (n \rightarrow \infty)$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} h(x_n) = C$.

Assume you know that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} h(x) = e$. If not, you can prove this by taking logarithms.

Now for any sequence $x_n \rightarrow \infty$, $g(x_n) \rightarrow \infty$ by assumption on $g$, so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} h(g(x_n)) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} h(x) = e$. Therefore $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} h(g(x))$ = e.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you realize that $h$ is continuous and its limiting value at infinity is $e$.

Now as $h$ is continuous, you can pull the limit inside, so that

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} h(g(x)) = h\left(\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)\right) = \lim_{y\to\infty} h(y) = e$$

**Added:** Since $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} h(x) = e$, for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists M > 0$ such that $|h(x) - e| < \epsilon$ for all $x \notin [-M,M]$.

Also, as $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x) = \infty$, $\exists N > 0$ such that $|g(x)| > M$ for all $x \notin [-N,N]$.

Hence we have for all $x \notin [-N,N]$,

$$ |h(g(x)) - e| < \epsilon$$.

whence $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}h(g(x)) = e$.

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy LateX. I an topping from phone.

Comment: Why h is continous at what point?

Comment: h is continuous at all $x > 0$.

Comment: It is continuous as it is a composition of continuous functions. The power and reciprocal are continuous functions.

Comment: @Vishal I took the liberty of cleaning up the latex, hope that's all right.

Comment: But we are calculating the limit at infinity. At infity h(x) and g(x) are not defined.

Comment: @T.Bongers Sure. In fact I am grateful.

Comment: That is why we need limits. No function is ever defined on infinity. values at infinity only make sense in terms of limit.

Comment: If you are still unclear, I recommend that you refresh your memory about limits at infinity.

Comment: I don't understand what rule you are using to say that $\lim_{x \to \infty} h(g(x))= h( \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x))= \lim_{y \to \infty} h(y)$. The rule of composition of function doesn't apply here because it requires h(x) to be continous at the point where the limit is being is evaluated.

Comment: @Mohan I edited my answer. See if it is clear now. And the above answer uses the same thing implicitly and does not even mention that. How come you accepted that answer?

Comment: The continuity of $h$ is irrelevant.

Comment: @Vishal Thanks for the answer. Yes, it is very clear now. The above answer uses the sequential definition of limit. The question becomes trivial once we use that.